# What is faster to render (and rerender) for browser in HTML: tables or flex-box

Tags: html, vue.js, browser, infinite-scroll

I need to make a table/table-like component on vue. It displays tabular data. Usually it has 5-30 rows and up to 30 columns. But elements in each cell are pretty heavy to render. Each has a couple of event listener, like @click and @hover, and those call methods that render even more components. They also have a lot of dynamic. It worked very well so far, but now there is a requirement to use this exact component for much larger number of rows, around 200. Obviously, the best way to go about it, is to implement pagination, since rendering so much of those cells would slow down browser immensly. But requirements explicitly says, that UI must not have any arrows to navigate between pages of table. Only acceptable way to go through table is to use scrolling (or infinite-scrolling), like it is all one page. So now i try to implement creating and destroying elements on scroll, when certain parts of table (like every 30th row) coming to view.

My question is, what would be faster to render as a table component?
Should i use a table component, like this?

```
  <table>
   <thead>
     <tr>
      <th v-for="date in dates">
        <span>Some dynamic components</span>
      </th>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr v-for="name in names">
      <th v-for="date in dates">
        <span>Some dynamic components</span>
      </th>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

or this?

```
<div class="TableLikeComponent">
 <div class="TableHeaderLikeComp">
  <div v-for="name in names" class="RowLikeComponent">
   <span>Some dynamic components</span>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="TableBodyLikeComp">
  <div v-for="name in names" class="RowLikeComponent">
   <div v-for="date in dates" class="ColumnLikeComponent">
    <span>Some dynamic components</span>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

or maybe there is even better solution?
Will be grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 0):

As much as I've previously looked into table library solutions, it seems that they all use `div` instead of native table for performance and customization.
From personal experience, native tables are often not easy to work with, requiring hackier solutions for complex problems that would be easy to achieve with `div`.

Comment: That is actually useful to know, thank you. But i still want to know if tables are faster to render.